# mysql - taking one row from one table based on ID and DATE and get multiple rows in another table if not show null values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `student` table which has name,student_id,date_of_exam,result,..
and another `result` table which has student_id,test_name,mark
test_name and marks will be multiple rows.
number of test are dynamic.. it is not static.

I need `table2.test_name` as header and show marks in my report

**table 1**

```
| id | name | date_of_exam|result|
------------------------------------------------
|  1 | gg   | 24-08-2016  | pass |
|  2 | hh   | 24-08-2016  | pass |
|  3 | ee   | 25-08-2016  | abse |
```

**table 2**

```
| student_id | test_name |mark |
-------------------------------------------------
|  1 | test1 | 20 |
|  1 | test2 | 40 |
|  1 | test3 | 50 |
|  2 | test1 | 30 |
|  2 | test2 | 50 |
```

**output should be**

```
| id | name | date_of_exam|result| test1 | test2 |test3 |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | gg   | 24-08-2016  | pass | 20    | 40    |   50 |
|  2 | hh   | 24-08-2016  | pass | 30    | 50    | NULL |
|  3 | ee   | 25-08-2016  | abse | NULL  | NULL  | NULL |
```

Comment: No. Don't bother with a pivot. Just handle the display issue in your application code.

Comment: the issue is i need to take all student ids and it should have all test names in header as columns.. im pushing those values in excel.

Comment: Yes. That's what application code's really good at (e.g. a PHP loop)

Answer (score 0):

Try this using CASE and Grouping:

```
SELECT table1.id,MAX(table1.name),MAX(table1.date_of_exam),MAX(table1.result),
       MAX(CASE WHEN table2.test_name = 'test1' THEN table2.mark END) as test1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN table2.test_name = 'test2' THEN table2.mark END) as test2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN table2.test_name = 'test3' THEN table2.mark END) as test3
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.id=table2.student_id)
GROUP BY table1.Id
```

<kbd>[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/943d39/3)</kbd>

Comment: It can be multiple test not limit to test3